# Excluding certain results of the query SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables: CLIENT, FEATURE, CLIENT_FEATURE

- Table `CLIENT`: id_client, name, surname, address
- Table `FEATURE`: id_feature, feature_txt
- Table `FEATURE_CLIENT`: id_fc, fc_id_client, fc_id_feature

One client can have multiple features.

If I want to see clients with desired 1 feature:

```
SELECT 
    [id_client], [name], [surname], [address], [id_feature], 
    [feature_txt], [id_fc], [fc_id_client], [fc_id_feature]
FROM 
    [client]
LEFT JOIN 
    [feature] ON fc_id_client = id_client
WHERE 
    fc_id_feature = 1
```

It is ok, but If the client has the feature 1 and 20 and I want to search for clients without feature 20

I tested:

```
SELECT 
    [id_client], [name], [surname], [address],[id_feature], 
    [feature_txt], [id_fc], [fc_id_client], [fc_id_feature]
FROM 
    [client]
LEFT JOIN 
    [feature] ON fc_id_client = id_client AND fc_id_client <> 20
WHERE 
    fc_id_client = 1
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Your column names are changing between the two examples...

Comment: Sorry, I translate the column names and omitted some. fixed it already.

Comment: You are referring to columns fc_id_client and fc_id_feature but the table FEATURE_CLIENT never appears in your query. Also you are using fc_id_feature and fc_id_client differently in the two queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    [client]
     INNER JOIN 
    [feature_client] ON 
        client.id_client = feature_client.fc_id_client 
     INNER JOIN 
    [feature] ON 
        feature_client.fc_id_feature = feature.id_feature
WHERE 
    fc_id_feature = 1 AND
    id_client NOT IN
      (
        SELECT fc_id_client
        FROM 
            feature_client 
             INNER JOIN 
            feature ON
                fc_id = id_feature 
        WHERE id_feature = 8
      )
```

Comment: Not really.
I have clients with many features:
John Doe1: 1,4,6, 8
John Doe2: 1,3,5, 2
John Doe3: 1,5,6, 8
John Doe4: 1,4,2, 3
John Doe5: 1,4,3, 8
I would like to see all clients with feature 1 without feature 8
So in my case: John Doe2, and John Doe4

Comment: That's not too much different from what I posted earlier - take a look at the revision and let me know if it makes sense.